# Can I make conan usage optional to users of my library that uses conan?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

Using conan to develop a library seems to force users of the library to also use conan. Is there a (standard) way I can replace the CONAN_PKG::protobuf reference in Targets.cmake with just protobuf?

### Context

I am using cmake to build a static C++ library using protobuf, using conan to handle the protobuf dependency, ie

```cpp
target_link_libraries(mylib
    PUBLIC
        CONAN_PKG::protobuf
    )
```

When I install this library locally , ie `ninja install` the created `MylibTargets.cmake` contains a reference to `CONAN_PKG::protobuf`

```cpp
set_target_properties(Mylib::Mylib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/mylib;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "CONAN_PKG::protobuf"
```

This forces users of my library to use conan to resolve the `CONAN_PKG::protobuf` dependency. (I want users of the library to be able to use the protobuf headerfiles).

I am using

```cpp
install(EXPORT MylibTargets
    FILE MylibTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE Mylib::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/mylib
    )
```

to generate MylibTargest.cmake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all the modern CMake integrations can achieve some level of transparent integration. First attempts are `cmake_find_package` and `cmake_find_package_multi`, but the most modern one are:

- CMakeDeps: [see docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html) generates `xxx-config.cmake` scripts, so consumers can do a normal `find_package(protobuf ...)`
- CMakeToolchain: [see docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmaketoolchain.html) generates a `conan_toolchain.cmake` to help mapping the Conan settings to CMake syntax (and can be used with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake`

With this integration, it is possible to keep CMakeLists.txt completely agnostic of Conan. This integration will become the standard one in Conan 2.0.

Comment: When I receive a notification about Conan here, drodri already answered 10 min before. Billy the kid, the fastest answer in Conan stackoverflow!

Comment: A followup question: Do I understand correctly that the suggested solution(s) means that my CMakeLists.txt does not use CONAN_PKG etc? Instead they will use find_package(...)?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the point. Consumer CMakeLists.txt is completely agnostic, no CONAN_PKG, just something like ``find_package(protobuf....)`` and ``target_link_libraries(myapp ... protobuf::protobuf)``